# .htaccess redirect products that start with a string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have various broken links of the form:

http://www.mysite.com/categA/categB/product*.html

(the final part of the url starts with the string "product")

and I want to create an .htaccess rule to redirect them to:

http://www.mysite.com/categC/categD/product*.html

...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^categA/categB/product(.+)\.html$ categC/categD/product$1.html [L,R=301]
```